# Adding zig-zag to y-axis between zero and first tick to a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I want to add a [zig-zag](http://www.dr-aart.nl/Formulas-graphs.html) to the bottom of an y-axis to a ggplot2 plot using [grid](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/00Index.html) functions. This should be doable by retrieving the axis grob from the [gtable](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/4beefa1fa985bebb5b3357efeacc7b83b82c784c/R/plot.r#L152-L159) that is created by the print and adding points to the horizontal line.

Here's a toy example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data(airquality)
data <- na.exclude(airquality)
model <- lm(Temp ~ Wind, data)

png(filename = "basic_plot.png", width=500, height=500, type = "cairo", res = 120)
ggplot(data=data, aes(y=Temp, x=Wind)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept=coef(model)[1],
              slope=coef(model)[2])+
  theme_bw()
dev.off()
```

[image: basic ggplot]

Here's the core idea (sorry the ugliness, Gimp is not the ideal tool for this):

[image: plot with zigzag]

The tools that I need help with are thus:

1. Find the axis-grob in gtable
2. Modify this by using [grid.edit](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.edit.html)

alternatively I've started looking at the ggplot-code but I haven't found where the axis grobs are created, ideally I would like to locate these and add a theme option that allows for this.

I'm aware of Hadley´s [concerns](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/jSrL_FnS8kc) to adding this feature but as I understand it this was mostly in the presence of scatterplots where I agree. My use case is a survival curve where it's important to notify that the bottom isn't 0%.

## Update

The core function for navigating the viewport tree is `seekViewpor` and in order to look at the tree we can use the `current.vpTree`:

```
library(grid)
current.vpTree()

# viewport[ROOT]->
#   (viewport[GRID.VP.397]->(
#     viewport[GRID.VP.398]), 
#    viewport[GRID.VP.399]->(viewport[GRID.VP.400]), 
#    viewport[GRID.VP.401]->(viewport[GRID.VP.402]), 
#    viewport[GRID.VP.404]->(viewport[GRID.VP.405]), 
#    viewport[layout]->(
#      viewport[panel.6-4-6-4], 
#      viewport[subtitle.3-4-3-4], 
#      viewport[xlab-b.8-4-8-4]->(viewport[GRID.VP.397]->(viewport[GRID.VP.398])), 
#      viewport[axis-r.6-5-6-5], 
#      viewport[title.2-4-2-4], 
#      viewport[spacer.5-5-5-5], 
#      viewport[background.1-7-10-1], 
#      viewport[xlab-t.4-4-4-4], 
#      viewport[axis-l.6-3-6-3]->(
#        viewport[GRID.VP.404]->(viewport[GRID.VP.405]), 
#        viewport[GRID.VP.406]->(
#          viewport[GRID.VP.404]->(viewport[GRID.VP.405]), 
#          viewport[axis]->(
#            viewport[axis.1-1-1-1]->(viewport[GRID.VP.404]->(viewport[GRID.VP.405])), 
#            viewport[axis.1-2-1-2]))), 
#      viewport[caption.9-4-9-4], 
#      viewport[ylab-l.6-2-6-2]->(viewport[GRID.VP.399]->(viewport[GRID.VP.400])), 
#      viewport[spacer.5-3-5-3], 
#      viewport[axis-b.7-4-7-4]->(
#        viewport[GRID.VP.401]->(viewport[GRID.VP.402]), 
#        viewport[GRID.VP.403]->(viewport[GRID.VP.401]->(viewport[GRID.VP.402]), 
#          viewport[axis]->(
#            viewport[axis.1-1-1-1], 
#            viewport[axis.2-1-2-1]->(
#              viewport[GRID.VP.401]->(
#                viewport[GRID.VP.402]))))), 
#      viewport[spacer.7-5-7-5], 
#      viewport[ylab-r.6-6-6-6], 
#      viewport[axis-t.5-4-5-4], 
#      viewport[spacer.7-3-7-3]))
```

The commented is a prettified output from ggplot. Note that some of the numbers are changed for every plot, i.e. GRID.VP.*397* changes betweeen plots. We can now navigate to the left axis and add a transparent rectangle around the y-axis:

```
seekViewport("axis-l.6-3-6-3")
grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill="#66666666"))
```

This results in:

[image]

The questions that remain are:

1. How to get a list of grobs within the viewport
2. How to edit the y-line grob (this may be part of a rectangle around the entire page)
3. The viewport is cropped and this may cause an issue with the zig-zag patterns that goes between grobs
4. How to get the location of the bottom y-tick as a starter point for the zig-zag